# howto to get the value of the first row in dataset?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am trying to get  2 column in dataset from a query
my query is:

```
SELECT  cs.name,cs.rank,w.idw ,w.name,w.address FROM  custom cs,work w WHERE cs.id='".$name."' and cs.idcs=w.idcs";
```

But  i don't want the result, which i would show to user will have duplicate info( where cs.name, cs. rank would showup in every row). i want to let user see the result like this:

```
**Custom's info:**
ID:xyzqwe
Name: ABC company
Rank: VIP

**Work list** 
ID| Name|Address
1 |A    | 123 adc
2 |B    | 432 cali
.............
```

I tried to  fill custom's info with

```
echo "Name:".mysqli_fetch_array($rs)->['cs.name'];
echo "Rank:".mysqli_fetch_array($rs)->['rank'];
```

but all i got is syntax error. I am newbie after all.
Please some one give me an advice or hint.
Thank in advance.

Comment: A basic MySQL tutorial explains how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from below code

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{ 
     $name =  $row['Name']; 
}
```

Comment: Actually i want to get the first row for some data in it then  use "echo" to print the format of table then print out the data. so if i do that then  i will use 2 loops, which i am avoiding.